# How should I convert this neo4j Cypher/Apoc load to neo4j-admin import?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo, neo4j-apoc

I am working with email data and parsing it with python which produces a csv every hour.  With that csv I have 5 separate `load csv commands` to create/update nodes and relationships. They are `NO ATTACHMENT OR LINK`, `URL ONLY`, `ATTACHMENT ONLY`, `URL AND ATTACHMENT`, and `Attachment to Attachment Name, FileName Node`.

I would like to automatically import these via batch job.  Because of my familiarity I wanted to just do it in python, but I have been looking around stack and other places and people are recommending `neo4j-admin import`.  From the documentation it looks very different than what I have been doing with `--nodes` and `--relationships`.  Can anyone help with showing me how to convert a `CYPHER/APOC LOAD CSV` example that I have created below into a `noe4j-admin import`?

```
// URL AND ATTACHMENT
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM ("file:///sessions/4_hour_parsed_and_ready.csv") AS row
MERGE (a:Sender { name: row.From, domain: row.Sender_Sub_Fld})
MERGE (b:Link { name: row.Url_Sub_Fld, topLevelDomain: row.Url_Tld, htmlEncodedMessage: row.HTML_Encoded})
MERGE (c:Attachment { name: row.FileHash, fileExtension: row.FileName_Ext, containsMultipleExtensions: row.MultipleExtensions})
MERGE (d:Recipient { name: row.To})
WITH a,b,c,d,row
WHERE NOT row.Url_Tld = "false" AND NOT row.FileHash = "false"
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(a, row.Outcome, {}, {}, b) YIELD rel as rel1
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(b, row.Outcome2, {}, {}, d) YIELD rel as rel2
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(a, row.Outcome, {}, {}, c) YIELD rel as rel3
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(c, row.Outcome2, {}, {}, d) YIELD rel as rel4
RETURN a,b,c,d
```

Or how I can wrap this code in py2neo.

Comment: You use neo4j-admin import for initial, one-off loads of data. It appears what you're looking to do would be delta data updates? Could you please confirm

Comment: Yes, I would start with the first hour of data I choose.  Lets say the 0 hundred hour and import.  Then the next hour run again.  Where the merge statement would only create new nodes and relationships if they didn't previously exist.  In example this data is only external to internal, so if a new employee is seen receiving email or if a new sender sends email inbound. @Lju

Comment: Ok, so you're doing periodic updates. In this situation neo4j-admin import would not be useable. You would need to adding data either via your LOAD CSV approach or perhaps via the drivers. If you were doing a one-off initial load of a large dataset, then neo4j-admin import would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a function that holds the server connection info and wrapped everything in a py2neo query then executed it.

```
import py_2_neo_pass
from py_2_neo_pass import db_server, db_user, db_password
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship

graph = Graph(ip_addr = db_server, username = db_user, password = db_password)

query='''
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM ("file:///sessions/4_hour_parsed_and_ready.csv") AS row
MERGE (a:Sender { name: row.From, domain: row.Sender_Sub_Fld})
MERGE (b:Link { name: row.Url_Sub_Fld, topLevelDomain: row.Url_Tld, htmlEncodedMessage: row.HTML_Encoded})
MERGE (c:Attachment { name: row.FileHash, fileExtension: row.FileName_Ext, containsMultipleExtensions: row.MultipleExtensions})
MERGE (d:Recipient { name: row.To})
WITH a,b,c,d,row
WHERE NOT row.Url_Tld = "false" AND NOT row.FileHash = "false"
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(a, row.Outcome, {}, {}, b) YIELD rel as rel1
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(b, row.Outcome2, {}, {}, d) YIELD rel as rel2
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(a, row.Outcome, {}, {}, c) YIELD rel as rel3
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(c, row.Outcome2, {}, {}, d) YIELD rel as rel4
RETURN a,b,c,d
'''

graph.run(query)
```